# is there any relation between $\sigma(n)$ and $\sigma(n+1)$ where sigma is the sum of all divisors?

Tags: number-theory

I have this problem related to abundants that asks to prove that 
$$
\sigma(n) \ge k \cdot n
$$
I'm looking for any relation between:  $\sigma(n)$ and $\sigma(n+1)$

Comment: The factorization of $n$ does not help us much to factor $n-1$ or $n+1$. Hence, there is no (useful) relation.

Comment: @Peter for instance, I found that the first 3-abundant number is 120(k=3), how can I prove that other 3-abundant numbers fulfill the condition above? (that what the question asks I see that it doesn't make any sense because as far as I searched in the oeis there is no formula relating to the distribution of k-abundant numbers )

Comment: Which numbers exactly should be proven to be $k$-abundant ?

Comment: @Peter the question is from a contest, I'm not sure if it allowed posting questions, it literally asks for finding examples where k =3, k=4 ... and then proving that those examples fulfill the condition $\sigma(n) \ge k \cdot n$
I'm not sure if I quite understand the meaning.

Comment: So, we only have to show that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ can be arbitary large ? If yes, consider the primorials $p$#$:=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots p$. If it is a running context, you can if you want delete the question.

Comment: @Peter how can I relate between sigma(n)/n and primorials?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100636/discussion-between-peter-and-ahmed-ben).